# where can i install files for MatchTemplare import

Tags: java, matlab, opencv

I'm really stuck trying to use java wrapper library for opencv's cvMatchTemplate. See this page for details http://www.larmor.com/portal/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=27&Itemid=60

Basically, I need to import com.larmor.opencv.MatchTemplate http://www.larmor.com/projects/JavaOpenCVMatchTemplate/doc/ but I can't find the .jar files which need to download locally and add to my classpath. The only file to download on the sourceforge website is TestMatchWebCamArea.java which imports com.lamor.opencv.MatchTemplate. Where is this file? How can I use this api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, you can find the jar file inside the zip: [link](http://ignum.dl.sourceforge.net/project/jmatchtemplate/jmatchtemplate/Version%200.5%20beta/JavaOpenCVMatchTemplate_v0.5b_win32.zip)

Seems this project is not active for a while. And the library will only work on win32 platforms since it includes a .dll.

Comment: Thanks! I see that there is a JavaOpenCVMatchTemplate_win32.jar file in the link you sent. I'm actually wanting to try this in matlab.

Comment: Also, how do I generally find a .jar file for java api? I'm confused... For example, I want to download the math package <http://show.docjava.com/book/cgij/code/data/j4pDoc/math/package-summary.html>. I found the documentation but how do I add this to my classpath? From my understanding I need either the class files or the jar files? I'm a bit new to java so please bear with me. ;-(

Comment: Yes, when you want to use an API, you need the corresponding classes. As a commodity, they are usually packaged in a jar file which the JVM can load. There are no defined way to resolve a jar. Some tools like Maven/Ivy/Gradles help for that but if you are a rookie don't go there immediately as their purposes are much wider

Comment: So for a given API where do I find the link to the corresponding jar files?

Comment: You google the jar file. Usually opensource projects have a web site and they have a link to their jar files. In sourceforge, you usually need to go to the "Files" section. There is no defined method to retrieve a jar.

Comment: I found a better solution in the form of jacacv. This is opencv for java. 
http://code.google.com/p/javacv/

Comment: These links are not working anymore. Can anyone give me this jar file? Thanks